# How do you specific elements in a list to another list without overwriting them? (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, loops, nested

I'm working on a code that reads in lists from a text file using nested loops. Right now it goes to a file via an inputted file path, then opens the file and converts everything in it into a list. This works well and fine.

However before it loops again and does the same for the rest of the inputted files I want it to automatically take the 6th from last element of each list that it just made put that into another list without overwriting anything. This is what I have so far:

```
listpath = "/Users/myname/Documents/list.txt"
lstfull = []
lstreduced = []


with open(listpath, "r") as flp:
    file_list = flp.readlines() #Makes a list from the file paths 
    fp = [x.strip() for x in file_list] #comprehension that removes \n from strings
    for i in fp: #list of file paths
        with open(i, "r") as f: #Opens each file from the file path
            for line in f:
                lstfull.append(line) #Takes each line and appends it to the list (lst)
                six = len(lstfull) - 6 #This is the element from each of the files I want
                lstreduced.append(lstfull[six])
```

Lists.txt is just a text file with a list of file paths that I can input such that I can have the code work from anywhere.

**The last line, (lstreduced.append(lstfull[si]), is where I run into issues.
I only want a listreduced to be made up of the 6th to last element from each of the inputted list but I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range. Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sixth last element from the end of a list can be accessed by using

```
lstfull[-6]
```

This should avoid IndexErrors as long as every list has at least 6 elements.

Is it possible that your code has an indentation error? It would make more sense if you were to do the following:

```
with open(listpath, "r") as flp:
    file_list = flp.readlines() #Makes a list from the file paths 
    fp = [x.strip() for x in file_list] #comprehension that removes \n from strings
    for i in fp: #list of file paths
        with open(i, "r") as f: #Opens each file from the file path
            for line in f:
                lstfull.append(line) #Takes each line and appends it to the list (lst)
            lstreduced.append(lstfull[-6])
```

Comment: Thank you this was right and my code it now working you're the best <3<3<3<3